# What is MAKEWORD used for?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have come across this macro `MAKEWORD(2,2)` in a piece of instructional code. I read in MSDN that it "*Creates a WORD value by concatenating the specified values.*"

The question is, isn't a WORD something like an unsigned integer why would I ever need to do such a strange procedure such as using `MAKEWORD()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The macro expects two bytes as its parameters:

```
WORD MAKEWORD(
  BYTE bLow,
  BYTE bHigh
);
```

Its defined in `Windef.h` as :

```
#define MAKEWORD(a,b)   ((WORD)(((BYTE)(a))|(((WORD)((BYTE)(b)))<<8)))
```

It basically builds a 16 bits words from two 1 bytes word (and doesn't look very portable)

The binary representation of the number 2 with 1 byte (a WORD) is :
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

If we take the concatenate two of those bytes as in `MAKEWORD(2,2)` , we get:

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Which is 512 + 2 = 514 : [live demo.](http://ideone.com/ucNxLG)

The only real life example of this particular macro is in the [Initialization of Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to generate the versioning word expected by `WSAStartup`.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand why this is done. Can you just do `WORD = 2.2;` I'm a beginner so this kind of thing is just strange to me.

Comment: @user3704920 , please see my edit for the binary explanation. 2.2 has nothing to do with this, MAKEWORD is not concatenating strings, but bits.

Comment: Any intended portability presumably comes from *the fact that a macro can be defined differently in the system-provided headers as-needed on systems or cross-compilers where endianness is different*, not from any one specific definition found in any given version of the header file you have.

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, `MAKEWORD(x,y)` is equivalent to `((y) << 8 | (x))`; this is useful when packing two byte-sized values into a single 16-bit field, as often happens with general-purpose message structures.  The complementary operation is performed by the `LOBYTE` and `HIBYTE` macros, which extracts the low- or high-order byte from a `WORD` operand.

The macro saw considerable use during the 16-bit days of Windows, but its importance declined once 32-bit programs came to dominance.  Another vestige of 16-bit Windows lies in the names of the `MSG` structure members `wParam` and `lParam`, which were originally typed `WORD` and `LONG` respectively; they're both `LONG` now.

Trememdous historical insight can be found in Charles Petzold's tome, [Programming Windows, second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556152647).

Comment: in this ((y) << 8 | (x); can you please tell why you have used 8 ?

Comment: @RaHuL Because a byte is an octet (eight bits) on most systems (probably all systems that Windows could ever run on). So if you're constructing one 16 bit value from two 8 bit halves, you want to shift one of them by 8 to line the bits up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Many small digital devices (for instance a digital thermometer) will store their data in 8-bit registers. An 8-bit register can store signed numbers between -127 and 127. So to store numbers lower than -127 or higher than 127 two 8-bit registers are used: lower significant 8 bits stored in register1 and the higher 8-bit in register2. The computer reading the data will need to fetch the data from the two registers and then reassemble the two values to produce a 16-bit number between -32767 and 32767. The MAKEWORD macro is a quick way to assemble the two small 8-bit numbers into one larger 16-bit number. If the data is even higher it will be store in even more 8-bit registers.
Hope this makes sense.