# using MAKEWORD function creates error E0109- expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++, json, winsock, winsock2

I'm writing a project using cpp, sockets, json and winsock2 to create a connection between server and client, I'm using the function WSAStartup from winsock2.h to start a connection. I copied the way it's used from codes from the internet and it worked for a while, until suddenly the MAKEWORD function created an error.

Here's the function I used MAKEWORD in it:
(Communicator, RequestHandelerFactory and m_handlerFactory are classes I created, ignore that)

```cpp
Communicator::Communicator(RequestHandelerFactory* RHF) : m_handlerFactory(RHF)
{
    WSADATA wsa_data = {};
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data) != 0)
    {
        throw std::exception("wsa startup failed");
    }
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    _serverSocket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (_serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__ " - socket");
    }
}
```

The includes and defines I used:

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <exception>
#include <minwindef.h>
#include <windef.h>
#include <ctime>
//some more includes from code I wrote

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

The error is appearing in MAKEWORD function, and no matter what I do, it's still giving the same error.

```
E0109 expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, if that changes anything.
I tried solving that in many ways, nothing seems to work.

Comment: How does this relate to C#?

Comment: I believe `MAKEWORD`  is a macro, not a function.

Comment: @vandench sorry, I'm using c# in the client code, I'm new on this website so I don't really know how it works here so I added every tag I thought was relevent.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no idea what marco is... :( but the point is the code isn't working although it supposed to

Comment: *no idea what marco is* -- That raises red flags if your job is to maintain / write C++ code.

Comment: `//some more includes from code I wrote` -- And one or more of those `#includes` may have affected the definition of the `MAKEWORD` macro in some way.  The way you solve problems like this is to erase *everything*, and slowly bring back the basic code, i.e. `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <winsock2.h>`, and then a simple `int main() { WSADATA wsa = {}; WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);` -- if that compiles, then introduce more code *slowly*, compile, etc. until the compilation breaks.  Then you will know what line(s) of code that were added to break the compilation.

Comment: Also, if you don't know the C++ language, it is not friendly enough for you to simply get code off of websites and hope that the code works.  Unless you understand what every line is supposed to do, you will have further issues down the road due to the lack of knowledge of C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for worrying, but it's not for work- it's for studying, I'm still learning c++. I asked my teacher about the code and now I understand it- but I still can't capture what went wrong... it worked before and supposed to work now.
How can #include effect the definition of MAKEWORD...?
I'll try checking the includes, but the whole code is too big to start over.
Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to "start over".  Create a new project and just do as stated in my previous comment.  If you want to be convinced, if that tiny program that uses MAKEWORD compiles successfully, what would the logical conclusion be as to why your larger program fails to compile?  As to why an include can affect MAKEWORD, this is the danger of macros in C++.  They are merely text replacement mechanisms, not real functions.  A subsequent macro (or even a previous one) can affect MAKEWORD if MAKEWORD itself uses other macros.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using `define` before my code. Thank you:)

Comment: Please provide more information. What did you `define` incorrectly? This isn't really an answer, because it doesn't provide sufficient information so that another person with the same problem will know how to fix it.

Comment: I only defined magic numbers, (```#define BYTE 8``` etc) but for some reason that was what made the code not to work.

Comment: That makes sense, because [the MAKEWORD macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131931/902497) assumes that `BYTE` is the name of an 8-bit integer type and that `WORD` is the name of a 16-bit integer type. If you change the definitions of `BYTE` and `WORD`, then the macro breaks.

Comment: @Noa -- Well, you now see the dangers of using macros like this.  If (and I mean a big **if**) you are going to use your own macros, do not use common names such as `BYTE`, or `FILE` or anything like that.  There is a good chance it will clash with other macros.  That's why third party libraries that unfortunately need to use macros use prefixes in the macro name (example, `MYLIBRARY_BYTE`), so that there is virtually no chance of names clashing.