# taking multiple lines of input in C++ / WinAPI recv() function from an accepted client connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

The problem seems to be in step 8. I am trying to use a while loop on the recv() function that I thought would allow me to keep appending to the RecvBuffer, but instead it just stalls and the program doesn't do anything. I am pretty sure I am missing something that would enable me to take multiple lines of input from a connected session, say, via netcat.exe for example. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

UPDATE: I made some edits, and I can now continue to input from the client connection, and these get sent, but I get weird outputs from the previous input and clearing the buffer doesn't seem to work.

The out put I get in the Server when I input "something goes here" from
`cout << "Receive success: " << RecvBuffer << " ----> end of input"<<endl;`
is this:

```
Receive success: g goes h ----> end of input
Receive success: ere
es h ----> end of input
```

I'm not sure why the above occurs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Tchar.h>
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "TCP SERVER" << endl;
    //LOCAL VARIABLES
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    int iWsaStartUp;
    int iWsaCleanUp;

    SOCKET TCPServerSocket;
    int iCloseSocket;

    struct sockaddr_in TCPServerAdd; //This is the structure
    struct sockaddr_in TCPClientAdd;
    int iTCPClientAdd = sizeof(TCPClientAdd);

    int iBind;

    int iListen;

    SOCKET sAcceptSocket;

    int iSend;
    char SenderBuffer[512] = "Hello from server!";
    int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer);

    int iRecv;
    char RecvBuffer[512] = "Input: ";
    int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;

    int newiRecv;
    char newRecvBuffer[512];
    int newiRecvBuffer = strlen(newRecvBuffer) + 1;

    //STEP 1: WSAStasrtup Function - initiates use of the Winsock DLL by a process
    //See the MSDN for a great guite for this and ALL of the processes here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winsock/initializing-winsock
    //and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winsock/creating-a-basic-winsock-application 
    
    iWsaStartUp = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata); //more info-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131843/what-is-makeword-used-for 
    if (iWsaStartUp != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup FAILED" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "WSAStartup Success" << endl;
    }
    //STEP 2 - FILL THE STRUCTURE
    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr);
    //TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); <------- this is now depreciated, so see the above line of code
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);


    //STEP 3: Create socket
    TCPServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (TCPServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "TCP Server socket gailed " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "TCP Server socket creation success" << endl;
    }

    //STEP 4: Bind
    iBind = bind(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd, sizeof(TCPServerAdd));
    if (iBind == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "bind failed with " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "bind success" << endl;
    }
    //STEP 5: listen
    
        iListen = listen(TCPServerSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iListen == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Listen function failed with " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Listen fucntiuon success" << endl;
        }
        //STEP 6: Accept
       
        sAcceptSocket = accept(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPClientAdd, &iTCPClientAdd);
        if (sAcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "accept failed with " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
             cout << "Accept success" << endl;
        }
            //STEP 7: send
           
            iSend = send(sAcceptSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
            if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "send failed with " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "send success" << endl;
            }
            //STEP 8: recv
            while (1) {
                iRecv = recv(sAcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
                
                if (iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    cout << "receive failed with " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Receive success: " << RecvBuffer << " ----> end of input"<<endl;
                }
               
                char txbuf[512];
                strcpy_s(txbuf, "you said: ");
                strcat_s(txbuf, RecvBuffer);
                send(sAcceptSocket, txbuf, strlen(txbuf) + 1, 0);


              
                
            }

}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? [`recv` can fail for a lot of reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recv) that aren't fatal. Also note that `iRecvBuffer` is likely initialized to the wrong value. You're taking the `strlen` of uninitialized memory (that's undefined behavior!!!!) instead of passing 511 bytes after zero initializing the buffer.

Comment: TCP/IP is a stream protocol not a line protocol (as the title implies) that means that `recv` could return only part of the 1st line, then the rest of line 1 and some of line 2 on the next call etc (ie there is not 1::1 relationship between `send` and `recv`) .  You need to use the return length and reassemble the data back into the sent messages.

Comment: @RichardCritten - you are right. I now have the desired behaviour, but only partial inputs are being returned. Do you have an example of how to  use the return length and reassemble the data back into the sent messages?

Comment: It's not too hard to write - basically call `recv` in a loop appending the received data (`recv` returns the length of data in the buffer don't assume `0` termination)  to a work-in-progress-buffer until you get a complete message (and usually some extra). Extract the complete message (keeping the extra). Repeat. Look out for corner cases eg more then one complete message in the buffer; `recv` errors etc

Comment: @IInspectable is there a way to use I/O Completion Ports without making your program Windows-only?

Comment: @jer Is there a way to use `WSAStartup` without making your program Windows-only? Seeing as making your program Windows-only is a question that has already been answered, all that's left is taking advantage of taking that decision.

Comment: @IInspectable I'll take that as a "no" :)  (btw my programs have WSAStartup() inside `#ifdef WIN32` so that they can still compile on other platforms)

Comment: @jer You cannot use I/O Completion Ports on systems that don't provide I/O Completion Ports. Once you have made the decision to not care about systems that don't provide I/O Completion Ports, I can't think of a reason not to use them. Well, maybe one reason: Writing code that wins benchmarks in favor of Linux.